# Why is my query only returning one row?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have three primary tables in this scenario: leage_ladders, league_squads and league_experience.  I am currently working on the ladder view page and would like to find all squads on the given ladder that have experience.  The query does not return any errors, however, it only returns one row, and I have no idea why.

Below is the query I am using:

```
$query_squads = "
            SELECT
                s.squad_id AS squad_id, s.ladder_id, s.team_id AS team_id,
                x.experience_id, x.squad_id, SUM(x.value) as total_exp
            FROM league_squads AS s
            LEFT JOIN league_experience AS x ON (s.squad_id = x.squad_id)
            WHERE s.ladder_id = ".$ladder_id."
            HAVING total_exp > 0
            ORDER BY total_exp DESC
            ";
```

Below are my tables:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `league_experience`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `league_experience` (
  `experience_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `squad_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `date_earned` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`experience_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `league_experience`
--

INSERT INTO `league_experience` (`experience_id`, `squad_id`, `value`, `date_earned`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 1, 500, '2013-09-03 07:10:59', 'For being ballers.'),
(2, 2, 250, '2013-09-03 07:10:52', 'For being awesome.');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `league_squads`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `league_squads` (
  `squad_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `team_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `ladder_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `date_joined` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `last_rank` tinyint(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`squad_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `league_squads`
--

INSERT INTO `league_squads` (`squad_id`, `team_id`, `ladder_id`, `date_joined`, `status`, `last_rank`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '2013-09-02 09:43:53', 0, 0),
(2, 2, 1, '2013-09-03 06:14:49', 0, 0);
```

The query should return two results when ladder_id 1 is visited.  But it only displays the first result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using an aggregate function `SUM()` without `GROUP BY` clause. What it does is it calculates the total sum of all filtered records and return a random value for non-aggregated column. Try adding `GROUP BY` clause,

```
WHERE ...
GROUP BY s.squad_id, s.ladder_id, s.team_idd, x.experience_id, x.squad_id
ORDER BY ...
```

According to MySQL Docs,

> If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY
>   clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows. For more
>   information, see [Section 12.15.3, **MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html).

Comment: Ah, yes.  Thank you.  Since you were the first one to actually post a solution, your answer will be accepted once it lets me!

Answer (score 0):

You have aggregate function in your select part: `SUM(x.value) as total_exp`. And because there's no `GROUP BY`, you'll get one row with total_exp sum of matched rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use aggregating function:

```
SUM(x.value) as total_exp
```

Which automatically groups rows.
And because you didn't defined `GROUP BY` clause, it groups all rows together.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you used SUM() aggregating function.

i fixed your SQL.

```
SELECT
s.squad_id AS squad_id, s.ladder_id, s.team_id AS team_id,
x.experience_id, x.squad_id, SUM(x.value) as total_exp
FROM league_squads AS s
LEFT JOIN league_experience AS x ON (s.squad_id = x.squad_id)
WHERE s.ladder_id = "1"
GROUP BY s.squad_id, s.ladder_id, s.team_id, x.experience_id
ORDER BY s.squad_id DESC
```

i just insert 1 line. to clarify. it make determining what to SUM(). surely, you can change this conditions.

```
GROUP BY s.squad_id, s.ladder_id, s.team_id, x.experience_id
```

thanks.